# show weekly winner with monthly array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have a table named winner of data 
DB table look like

```
   id   |   name   |  userid  |  score   |      date      |
   ------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   john   |    4     |   233    |  2014-02-02 
2   |   mary   |    5     |  1256    |  2013-02-05  
3   |   john   |    6     |   100    |  2013-03-08 
4   |   elvis  |    7     |   123    |  2013-03-04 
5   |   john   |    2     |   1234   |  2013-03-02
```

But I want to show  result Like .every week have maximum 4 item based on maximum score.I cant understand how to do it

```
"monthly_winners":[
    {
        "id":"2",
        "score":"1256",
        "month":"Feb"


    "weekly_winners":[
            {
                  "id":"1",
                  "score":"1256",
            },
            {
                  "id":"2",
                  "score":"233","
            },

        ],



    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "score":"1234",
        "month":"Mar"


    "weekly_winners":[
            {
                  "id":"5",
                  "score":"1234",
            },
            {
                  "id":"4",
                  "score":"123","
            },

        ],


    }


],
```

I am trying many times but i can show only monthly winner.

Comment: You say that you want the 4 highest scores per week, but your sample output shows the highest scores of 4 weeks.  It also shows the weeks distributed into calendar months, but weeks will sometimes span a calendar month - how should that be handled?

Comment: i am confused @eggyal

Comment: About anything in particular, or just life generally?